# Is this question physically possible?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, vectors

Question: Two smooth vertical walls stand on a smooth horizontal plane and intersect at right angles. A small smooth sphere of mass m is moving with velocity (4i + 3j) m/s when it hits one of the walls. It rebounds from the wall with velocity (i + 3j) m/s and goes on to hit the second wall. Given that the coefficient of restitution between the sphere and each wall is the same, find the total kinetic energy lost by the sphere in both collisions

Problem I have: When I worked on this I get an impulse from the first collision of -3mi (which wouldn't be perpendicular to the first wall). So surely this problem doesn't "work" (unless I have made a mistake)

[image]

Comment: Considering we know nothing about the orientation of the walls it's hard to tell how perpendicular this is to said walls, you should provide a picture to clearly show what's going on. Also your units of impulse aren't correct.

Comment: As given, the answer does not seem to have a well-defined answer because the angle of the two incidents will be different, and thus a different amount of energy will be lost in each collision. And this is even before considering that a sphere has an angular momentum. In reality, the first collision will change the rotational state of the sphere, which will influence the result of the second collision. If the sphere is assumed perfectly slippery (no angular momentum change), it's impossible to loose momentum parallel to the wall it collides with, so energy loss must dependent on incident angle.

Comment: Why is this on hold? The OP has clearly "shown some effort" and has a specific concept they've identified (potential intractibility). I'm getting sick of mods flagging every question that looks homework like without actually understanding SO's policy themselves. It ruins it for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the impulse isn't perpendicular to the wall so the restitutive coefficient will be both vertical and horizontal to the wall.

The fact that it says that the coefficient of restitution is the same for each wall implies that it is invariant to incident angle (not in any way realistic, but hey that's what logically must be concluded) and that these components will be the same.

Thus you can figure out the wall angle by balancing the horizontal and vertical components to equal. Then go on to the other wall.

More likely the examiner made a mistake and one of the i velocity component should have changed sign.